Count arrangements of numbers in a grid, in which a consecutive path exists
How many ways can the numbers from $1$ to $16$ be placed in a $4\times4$ grid (or more generally, numbers from $1$ to $n^2$ in an $n\times n$ grid), with one number per cell, in such a way that any two consecutive numbers share either an edge or a corner?
I was doing a puzzle called "Math Path". An example completed puzzle:

To solve, consecutive numbers must share a corner or edge, and the arithmetic operations (if they exist) in the bold-outlined boxes must be obeyed.
This made me wonder about the question I've asked. Ignoring the bold boxes and arithmetic operations, just how many different path-containing grids exist?
I'm not really sure how to make much progress on it. Placing numbers from $1$ to $4$ in a $2\times2$ grid is easy. Each pair of cells are neighbors, so they can be placed in $4!=24$ ways. However, each grid can be rotated and/or reflected in $8$ ways, so there are $\frac{24}{8}=3$ "distinct" ways.
I tried placing $1$ to $9$ in a $3\times3$ grid, but got stuck. I can't think of an effective way to break it into cases (e.g. I thought about $1$ in the middle, $1$ in a corner, $1$ in an edge square, but that didn't lead anywhere).
I'm looking either for a complete answer, or just hints in the right direction.

One brute-force approach would be to enumerate all possible such boards. But there are $16! \approx 2\times 10^{13}$ possible boards; we can reduce this by an order of magnitude if we use symmetry, but this still seems too high for a computational approach to be very useful.

https://oeis.org/A158651

Very good! I had a hunch someone would come through with an OEIS link. So it's not something easily computed by hand or a simple formula.
